# Create a DRM Compatible reader?

Tags: epub, kobo, drm, adobe-digital-editions, apps

If I were to create an ePub reader application for mobile devices, how could I receive authorization to allow DRM protected books purchased from other eBook stores to run on my app (legal only, no workaround)?
For instance, how could I allow an Adobe DRM protected book purchased from Kobo to be read on my app?

Thanks for any insight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon and Apple have their own DRM schemes and you won't be able to create an ereader that opens books from their stores. But most others use Adobe DRM, and you can license Adobe's Reader Mobile SDK to do this. ARMSDK is very expensive (when I was involved with a related project many years ago, it was many thousands of dollars a year for a license), and it is difficult to work with.

You may find these links helpful:

- [An overview of related tech on the Bluefire blog](http://www.bluefirereader.com/blog/?p=57)
- [A decent sales page for ARMSDK](https://www.datalogics.com/products/digitalpublishing/rmsdk/)